# Visual Studio overlapping groupboxes

Tags: visual-studio

`
namespace Simple_ATM
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

```
    Personal_İnformation Personal = new Personal_İnformation();





    private void Exit_Login() {

        LoginScreen.Visible = false;
        LoginScreen.Enabled = false;
  

    }

   private void Enter_Clientİnfo()
    {

        Client_İnfo.Visible = true;
        Client_İnfo.Enabled = true;
        Client_İnfo.Location = LoginScreen.Location;
        UI_Control.Text = "2";

    }




    private void b2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      

        switch (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text))
        {
            case Personal_İnformation.password1 :
                Exit_Login();
                Enter_Clientİnfo();
                

                Client_Name.Text = Personal_İnformation.Name1;
                Client_Surname.Text = Personal_İnformation.SurName1;
                Client_GSMnumber.Text = Personal_İnformation.PhoneNumber1;
                Client_BankNumber.Text = Personal_İnformation.BankNumber1;
                break;

            case Personal_İnformation.password2 :
                Exit_Login();
                break;

            case Personal_İnformation.password3 :
                Exit_Login();
                break;

            case Personal_İnformation.password4 :
                Exit_Login();
                break;


            default:
                break;
        } //Password Check in login screen
```

`I want to create 2 overlapping group boxes but when I press the button one will open and one will close. I wrote the code as attached but it didn't work  gb1 became invisible but gb2 not became visible.[I try this code but ıts didnt worked. Login_Screen and Client info is different GroupBoxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcTBm.png)

Comment: Don't post a picture of the code: post the actual code. That makes it easier to propose a solution (because, with a picture, we have to type in all the code rather than editing it and posting it!)

Comment: To address your concern: try adding the code in the second method into the first (so you have a total of 4 lines.) You're making the first box invisible -- but it looks like the second method isn't getting called, probably because you can't enter into the group box until it's already visible!

Comment: Also, I am assuming this is C#, but I don't know for sure because you didn't tag the question with the language or platform. Is it for Windows Forms? WPF? Something else?

Comment: @AnnL. Thanks for the replies and directions. yes, I'm using c#, I changed the commands as you suggested, but there was no change in my problem. 2.Group box is still not visible when the necessary conditions are met :( (I added the commands too. Thanks again) (Sorry for my newbie, I'm pretty new to software stuff :P)